# Formatting colnames to be read by cbind

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, cbind, tapply

Say I have a list called df such that  `colnames(df)` yields:

```
"A"           "B"          "C"                 "D"           "E"                 "F"
```

I would like aggregate data in the following way:

```
aggregate(cbind(`C`,`D`,`E`,`F`)~A+B, data = df, FUN = sum)
```

Of course I could do it "manually" but in my true data I have a very big amount of columns, so I am trying to change the  `colnames(df)[3:6]` output to yield:

```
`C`,`D`,`E`,`F`
```

instead. So far I have tried to use `toString(colnames(df)[3:6])` which yields:

```
"C, D, E, F"
```

But this is not read properly by `cbind`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `aggregate(cbind(C,D,E,F)~A+B, data = df, FUN = sum)`

Comment: Or `aggregate(. ~ A + B, data = df, FUN = sum)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `cbind` you could also use a matrix created from the subsetted data frame.

```
aggregate(as.matrix(df[names(df)[3:6]])~A+B, data=df, FUN=sum)
#       A     B     C     D     E     F
# 1  0.36 -0.11  2.02  2.29 -0.13 -2.66
# 2 -0.56  0.40 -0.09  1.30 -0.28 -0.28
# 3  1.37  0.63  1.51 -0.06 -1.39  0.64
```

Or, to answer your question literally try

```
(ev <- sprintf("cbind(%s)", toString(names(df)[3:6])))
# [1] "cbind(C, D, E, F)"
```

I don't think the backticks are needed. Are they?

And then, of course:

```
aggregate(eval(parse(text=ev))~A+B, data=df, FUN=sum)
#       A     B     C     D    E     F
# 1 -2.44 -1.78  1.90 -1.76 0.46 -0.61
# 2  1.32 -0.17 -0.43  0.46 0.70  0.50
# 3 -0.31  1.21 -0.26 -0.64 1.04 -1.72
```

---

*Data:*

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(-2.44, 1.32, -0.31), B = c(-1.78, -0.17, 
1.21), C = c(1.9, -0.43, -0.26), D = c(-1.76, 0.46, -0.64), E = c(0.46, 
0.7, 1.04), F = c(-0.61, 0.5, -1.72)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! It seems like the backticks are indeed needed cause they are imported from the csv as part of the column name. Would there be an easy way to get them back, or just remove them from the colnames?

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez Yeah I'd recommend to get rid of them using `names(df) <- gsub("\`", "", names(df))`.

Comment: @WeierstraßRamirez Actually I'm curious how your data looks like, could you create a small example as I did? Just use `dput` as it's described [here under "Copying original data"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/6574038), which is the usual way to share data on Stack Overflow.

Comment: So actually, I think the problem is that R adds the backticks since I have compound colnames in my data, this is from the actual colnames(df): [1] "CATEGORY"    "PARENT"      "BRAND"       "MEDIA"       "PROPERTY"    "TOTAL DOLS"  "TOTAL UNITS"
 [8] "2011  DOLS"  "2011  UNITS" "2012  DOLS"  "2012  UNITS" "2013  DOLS"  "2013  UNITS" "2014  DOLS" 
[15] "2014  UNITS"